# how to generate .htaccess password locally (by ruby)?

Tags: ruby, .htaccess

Is there a ruby script to generate password for `.htpasswd`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTAuth](http://copiousfreetime.rubyforge.org/htauth/) is a pure Ruby implementation of the Apache htpasswd and htdigest utilities.
It also sports an API so you can use the functionality from within your own Ruby code without running external scripts.